# How do I install Signal in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, instant-messaging

[Signal](https://www.signal.org/) is a cross-platform encrypted messaging service developed by the Signal Foundation and Signal Messenger. It uses the Internet to send one-to-one and group messages, which can include files, voice notes, images and videos.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Open your terminal and copy-paste the below command one by one

```
sudo apt install curl
curl -s https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install signal-desktop
```

All credit goes to https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-signal-desktop-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/

Comment: @mubasshir00 concerning your credits: actually, these instructions can also be found (identically) on [Signal download](https://signal.org/en/download/#) page behind the link **Signal for Linux - Debian-based distros** (bottom right).

Comment: What about ubunto 20.04 or higher ?

Comment: same way for 20.04 or higher @Eric

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @Eric What errors did you get, at what point in the process? Help us fix it.

Answer (score 31):

For all releases of Ubuntu 18.04 and newer:

`sudo snap install signal-desktop`

- The snap is provided by the all-volunteer [Snapcrafters team](https://github.com/snapcrafters/), a group of experienced and trusted experts from the Ubuntu Community who have been providing safe and secure snap packaging and regular updates for their adopted applications since 2017. The upstream Signal project does not provide a Snap package.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from a [deb package from the Signal PPA](https://signal.org/download/) and [snap package](https://snapcraft.io/signal-desktop) (sudo snap install signal-desktop), you can install it as [**flatpak**](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.signal.Signal) (Follow the [setup guide](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/) before installing):

```
sudo apt install flatpak  
flatpak install flathub org.signal.Signal
```

Once installed, you can run it from the menu or use the following command in the terminal:

```
flatpak run org.signal.Signal
```

If you don't have/want to enable/d the Flathub repository:

```
flatpak install https://dl.flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.signal.Signal.flatpakref
```

[image]

Source: [How to Install Signal on Ubuntu & Other Linux Distributions](https://itsfoss.com/install-signal-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

Conveniently from the **Ubuntu Software App** (see below) as a snap package (no terminal command needed).
Once opened, type the **`Signal Desktop` keyword** in the search bar. Click on the Signal Desktop option available.
Now, click on the **Install button** available under the Signal Desktop to begin the installation.
For more **details regarding the packaging**, see [comments of the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306915/how-do-i-install-signal-in-ubuntu/1307717#comment2223439_1306923).

More details (e.g. how to remove it) and pictures, see [Vitux page](https://vitux.com/signal-messenger-ubuntu/).
[image]